# Play Framework 2.2 using Inheritance in Teamplate

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a problem handling inheritance models in a form.  Here a simple example to understand my problem.

The class User has two subclasses Employee and Admin.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public class User extends Model {
 ...
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("employee")
public class Employee extends User{
    ...
}
```

**Admin.java**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("admin")
public class Admin extends AnalysisProcedure {
 ...
}
```

Now I want to assign multiple users to a project with a List. The list should hold objects of Employee or Admin.

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
public class Project extends Model {

public List<User> users;

}
```

The web interface is generated like this:

```
@repeat(projectForm("users")) { user =>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @inputText(user("name"))
        </td>
        ...
    <tr>
}
```

Performing the submit no error is shown, but also no new object is hold in the database. While debugging the code I see that the instance of the new user is User.

**Projets.java (Controller)**

```
...
Project project = formProject.get();
List<User> users = project.users;

for(User user : users){
    // the user is everytime instance of User
}
...
```

Now my question is how to handle this kind of inheritance in the web interface, so a Employee or an Admin can be added to the database?

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit problematic, although you are using i.e. `List<User>`, Java recognizes it as a `Employee` for an instance, so you need to *cast* the `Employee` to `User` (for relations saving that's enough if the object contains `id` field only.

For very similar problem with saving relations in Ebean we created simply *casting* method in `User` model, not really nice anyway works as expected:

```java
public User asUser() {
    User user = new User();
    user.id = this.id;
    return user;
}
```

Case:

```java
Employee employee = Employee.find.byId(123);

// This doesn't work:
project.users.add(employee);


// This works:
project.users.add(employee.asUser());
```